# Wrap Model.create in custom static create

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I would like to wrap the Mongoose [Model.create](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) method inside my own [static](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) create method:

```
// File: Task.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

// Custom static create method
taskSchema.statics.create = function (task) {
    console.log('CREATING TASK');
    return this.model('Task').create(task); // should call Mongoose `create`, not my custom static.
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

Usage is as follows:

```
// Usage:
var Task = require('Task.js');
var promise = Task.create(taskObject); // call custom static `create`.
```

But that doesn't work. It logs `CREATING TASK` many times before returning `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

I suspect `this.model('Task').create(task)` calls my custom static `create` method instead of the mongoose `create` method, thus leading to an infinity loop. If I rename my custom method to `myCreate` for example, everything works as expected.

How can I still have my `create` method but call mongoose `create` inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `Function.prototype.call()` to call the `Model.create()` function with the model you need:

```
taskSchema.statics.create = function (task) {
    console.log('CREATING TASK');
    return mongoose.Model.create.call(this.model('Task'), task);
};
```

So this will call `mongoose.Model.create(task)` and set the "this" of the function call to be `this.model('Task')`.